# Building chat application with java spring boot and open fire server

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, openfire

I have started to implement the chat application as part of web application. for that thinking to use open fire with spring boot. I have all the rest API which the open fire will provide. I need some reference document for accessing and implementing the chat application.

I have created the service for creating chat room like below,

```
@Override
    public ResponseEntity<BaseEntityResponse<Chatroom>> createChatRoom(String authorization,Chatroom chatroom) {
    Chatroom chat=new Chatroom();
    System.out.println("CHat room object in service: "+chatroom);
    chat.setRoomName(chatroom.getRoomName().toLowerCase());
    chat.setNaturalName(chatroom.getNaturalName().toLowerCase());
    chat.setDescription(chatroom.getDescription().toLowerCase());

    BaseEntityResponse<Chatroom> chatResponse = new BaseEntityResponse<>();
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    try{
            MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
            headers.add("Authorization", authorization);
            headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
            headers.add("Accept", "application/json");

            restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
            HttpEntity<Chatroom> requestObject = new HttpEntity<Chatroom>(chat, headers);
            ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity=restTemplate.postForEntity("http://10.182.207.48:9090/plugins/restapi/v1/chatrooms", requestObject,String.class);

            int statusCode = responseEntity.getStatusCodeValue();


            if(statusCode==200){
                //response.setResponseCode(statusCode);
                return new ResponseEntity<BaseEntityResponse<Chatroom>>(chatResponse, HttpStatus.OK);
            }else{
                //response.setResponseCode(MessageConstant.ResponseCode.ProcessFail.value());} 
                return  new ResponseEntity<BaseEntityResponse<Chatroom>>(chatResponse, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
            }
    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {   
//      response.setResponseCode(MessageConstant.ResponseCode.ProcessFail.value());
//      response.setResponseMessage(MessageConstant.CodeMessage.ProcessFail.value());
//      return response;
        return  new ResponseEntity<BaseEntityResponse<Chatroom>>(chatResponse, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }


}
```

My controller method is like as,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/createChatRoom", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json;charset=UTF-8",produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
    public ResponseEntity<BaseEntityResponse<Chatroom>> createChatRoom(@RequestBody Chatroom chatroom) {
        logger.debug("Entering inside create Chat Room method");
        System.out.printf("CHat room object",chatroom);
        //logger.debug("Create user request :  {}" , createUserRequestEntity);
        return chatService.createChatRoom("authorization",chatroom);
    }
```

Modal class for Chat is,

```
public class Chatroom {

    private String roomName;
    private String naturalName;
    private String description;
    <----getters and asetters---->
    }
```

I am getting error like,

```
 ERROR 11136 --- [nio-9090-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/printshopws] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
```

On postman I am getting response like,

```
{
    "timestamp": 1532328782602,
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": "java.lang.NullPointerException",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/webservices/chat/createChatRoom"
}
```

I am sending request body like,

```
{
"roomName": "room",
"naturalName": "Chatroom",
"description": "chat room"
}
```

Does any one has any documentation regarding the implementation of open fire services? Please reply.

Comment: Did you got the solution for this?

Comment: The error in your case is NullPointerException, which means some issue in your code. Did you check the complete stack trace?